# magento 2 Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'after': The attribute 'after' is not allowed

Tags: magento

I'm getting this error in magento 2. I didn't do any updates, this error just suddenly appeared.

I see that I have to remove the "after" attribute, but where can I find where?

```html
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'after': The attribute 'after' is not allowed.
Line: 1251


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'after': The attribute 'after' is not allowed.
Line: 1251

#0 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<layout xmlns:x...')
#1 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:x...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, NULL, '/www/htdocs/w00...', '%message%\nLine:...')
#2 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#3 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#4 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#5 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php(125): Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(Array)
#6 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(461): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:x...', 'layout_merged', false)
#7 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(442): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend...', '<body>\n   <refe...')
#8 /www/htdocs/domain/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load(Array)
#9 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load()
#10 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()
#11 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(254): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#12 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(875): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#13 /www/htdocs/domain/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#14 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#15 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Noroute/Index.php(44): Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor), 'no-route')
#16 /www/htdocs/domain/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Noroute/Index/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index->execute()
#17 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#18 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#20 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /www/htdocs/domain/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Noroute/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#22 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#25 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/mirasvit/module-search-autocomplete/src/SearchAutocomplete/Plugin/ResponsePlugin.php(157): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Mirasvit\SearchAutocomplete\Plugin\ResponsePlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /www/htdocs/domain/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#33 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /www/htdocs/domain/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#35 /www/htdocs/domain/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#36 {main}
```

I see that I have to remove the "after" attribute, but where can I find where?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can not add after attribute in referenceContainer. If you want to move Container then use it.

```
    <move element="element name" destination="where you want to move" after="">
```

Comment: I didn't add anything. I've made no coding on the site, just magento and plugin install

Which container should I remove? Where is it? How can I find?

Comment: You will  have to add a new ticket to extension          support because this is extension problem. You can check all the xml file in path .                                      app/code/vendor_name/module_name/view/frontend/layout/

Answer (score 1):

I think, You are using magento2.2 version. In this version, There is some modification in layout xml. You can not use `after` and `before` attribute in `referenceContainer` tag.

To solve this issue, You have to remove `after` and `before` attribute from `referenceContainer`.

you can use `move` tag for rearranging layout

Answer (score 0):

You will  have to add a new ticket to extension support because this is extension problem. You can check all the xml file in path                                       app/code/vendor_name/module_name/view/frontend/layout/

Answer (score 0):

As zed stated, this looks more like an upgrade issue to v2.2.x as they made the layout formatting stricter and some things which were allowed before are no longer.

The `before` and `after` attributes in `referenceContainer` tags are no longer valid.

Also we found that a `move` tag was also no longer allowed inside a `referenceBlock` tag either.

To find where these issues were at, I went into the `vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php` file and in the `_initDom()` method output the `$xml` variable to find the actual xml code at line xxx per an exception like the one OP has above.